# Predicate from Function Reference (of boolean type)

Tags: java, java-8, predicate, functional-interface

I need to compose a stream operation with a predicate based on a boolean function. Found a workaround via rethrowing a method's argument as a predicate, as shown:

```
public <T> Predicate<T> pred(final Predicate<T> aLambda) {
    return aLambda;
}

public List<String> foo() {
    return new ArrayList<String>().stream() //of course, this does nothing, simplified
            .filter(pred(String::isEmpty).negate())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The 'pred' method seems to do nothing, however not this:

```
public List<String> foo() {
    return new ArrayList<String>().stream() 
            .filter((String::isEmpty).negate()) 
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

nor any in-line conversion:

```
public List<String> foo() {
    return new ArrayList<String>().stream() 
            .filter(((Predicate)String::isEmpty).negate())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

seems to work. Fails with the error

> The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

What the fancy conversion happens in the 'pred(...)' method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write a utility method:

```
class PredicateUtils {

    public static <T> Predicate<T> not(Predicate<T> predicate) {
        return predicate.negate();
    }

}
```

and use it as follows:

```
.filter(not(String::isEmpty))
```

I believe it's more readable than casting to a `Predicate<T>`:

```
.filter(((Predicate<String>)String::isEmpty).negate())
```

Though I would go with a simple lambda:

```
s -> !s.isEmpty()
```

> What the fancy conversion happens in the `pred(...)` method?

You have specified a context - the type to work with. For instance, a `String::isEmpty` could be a `Function<String, Boolean>`, or `Predicate<String>`, or my `@FunctionalInterface`, or something else.

You clearly said that you were expecting a `Predicate<T>`, and you would return an instance of the `Predicate<T>`. The compiler is now able to figure out what the type you want to use.

Comment: You should place `s -> !s.isEmpty()` at the beginning of the answer…

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
((Predicate<String>) String::isEmpty).negate()
```

(note the use of the proper generic type)

or (preferred):

```
s -> !s.isEmpty()
```

which is way simpler and readable.

Answer (score 2):

Your third version almost worked:

```
Arrays.<String>asList("Foo", "Bar", "").stream() 
        .filter(((Predicate<String>)String::isEmpty).negate())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This seems to compile just fine.